Let's talk about this
Looking for better understanding about the below phrase.

Let's talk about this.

Is this phrase used to explain anything in step by step way?
As always! Thank You.

Let's talk about this can be used in general discussions and is not limited to things that require step-by-step explanations.  Google Books has lots of examples of such general use.
Of course in any discussions, things should be talked about in step-by-step manner, unlike quarrels.

Ok. "things should be talked about". Here should is strong emphasis?

We use should here to refer to doing the correct thing, not so much on giving strong emphasis.

Correct things should be strong emphasis. Yes/No.

@Nadeem Learning Center -Online, This is the right thing to do, and we should (or must) do it.  Both are possible; must gives the emphasis.
